# Why Im getting this "rain" noise in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

Hey guys Im trying to render my projest but Im getting this rain nose I don't know why, any suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: if you have chosen the Cycles render engine you probably need to increase the Sampling value in the Render panel

Answer (score 1):

Cycles is a tracing rendering engine, which means each point is calculated by tracing a path.

To get less noise, you have to [increase the sampling value](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/sampling.html) (more path), and apply a [denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/denoising.html).

There are many tutorial regarding the cycle rending, you might want to check them out.